# 'qt' best approach to Bold or change the size of QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in 'qt' programing and I am writing a simple text editor using 'QPlainTextEdit' .

I already asked my question in "[qt forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27343/)" but didn't get a response .

*I have two 'QPushButton' to bold and italicize but the problem is that they edit the whole text not the selected ones .*

*There is the same problem when I try to change the font size*

In Main I have :

```
 this->B_flag=false;
 this->I_flag=false;
 this->Font_Size=15;
 QFont newFont("Courier", this->Font_Size, QFont::Normal, false);
 textEdit->setFont(newFont);
```

In Method :

```
 void MainWindow::setItalic()
 {
 QFont newFont("Courier", this->Font_Size);
 if(this->I_flag==false){
     newFont.setItalic(true);
     this->I_flag=true;
 }
 else{
     newFont.setItalic(false);
     this->I_flag=false;
 }
 newFont.setBold(this->B_flag);
 textEdit->setFont(newFont);
 }
```

I have a Similar function to set Bold.

Similar approch to change size:

```
 void MainWindow::setNormal()
 {
 this->Font_Size=25;
 QFont newFont("Courier", Font_Size);
 newFont.setBold(this->B_flag);
 newFont.setItalic(this->I_flag);
 textEdit->setFont(newFont);
 }
```

This is the screenshot :

s22.postimg.org/b28r9tjap/before.jpg

s8.postimg.org/urxj51s9x/after.jpg

and The whole code just in case :

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g2hq0dmk9768ps5/v_3kUsxdQl

It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Please look at the docs, especially [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-application.html). You're setting the font on the whole widget, so of course the whole thing is changed.

Comment: @Mat I just finished reading that article ~ Yes I am changing the font of the whole widget ~ But what how I can change font properly ?

Comment: Look at the other examples listed in the QPlainTextEdit docs (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html). (Sorry I thought that one had bold/italics handling.)

Comment: I believe, what you need is `void QTextCursor::setCharFormat ( const QTextCharFormat & format )` and `void QTextCursor::mergeCharFormat ( const QTextCharFormat & modifier )`